# Unable to install kafka globally on my machine

Tags: macos, apache-kafka, zsh

Followed below mentioned steps to install kafka

Installed Apache kafka from kafke.apache.org

Have java8 already installed on my mac machine

Extracted kafka

Able to do cd kafka_2.13-2.7.0 and bin/kafka-topics.sh

But when I'm adding kafka in the bash_profiles then kafka is not added globally

nano ~/.bash_profiles
export PATH="$PATH:/mydirectorypath/Kafka_2.13-2.7.0/bin"
But when i'm trying to use kafka globally it doesn't work.

I'm new to mac and kafka both so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong is it the correct way to add paths in mac since in the first place i couldn't find existing bash_profiles using cat ~/.bash_profile
But after creating the one using nano ~ /.bash_profile i can see the content.
If i'm trying to do
Kafka-
It says zsh:command not found:kafka-

Answer (score 0):

> :is it the correct way to add paths in mac since in the first place i couldn't find existing bash_profiles

That export command is the correct way to set the path, however, according to the error, you're using ZSH, which does not use `.bash*` files. You'd need to edit `.zshrc` or change your default terminal back to Bash. You'd also need to start a new terminal after editing those files

To verify the PATH works, you'd do `which kafka-topics`

If you want to install Kafka on a Mac, just do `brew install kafka`. Then to run a broker, you can use `brew services` command with Zookeeper and Kafka to start/stop the servers, and your PATH will already have all the shell scripts - https://brew.sh

Note: The above are all local variables to your user account. Globally would imply the commands are available to any user logged in to your machine